# How early can I get the conversation started with a prospective postdoc advisor?

Tags: application, postdocs, job-search, europe

I am a little more than a year away from my funding running out (not taking into account any Covid-related extensions which may or may not be granted and thus can't be relied on). Hence, I would consider this date the target end date for my PhD after which I would like to move on from my current institution.

I have identified a handful of potential advisors for postdocs (in Europe, mostly). How early should/can I get in touch with them? Obviously, I would like to do it as early as possible (as there is a chance that means I can plan better). However, I don't want to do it too early to the point where it would seem weird / be pointless.

I am in science doing my PhD in Europe, should that be of help.

Comment: Do these people know you already?

Comment: Are you looking to apply for funding/fellowships for the position, or are you looking for positions funded by the advisor (through their instution/grants)?

Comment: @Buffy No. At least not in the sense that there was any collaboration.

Comment: @mmeent Ideally, the latter although I wouldn’t mind doing the former if an advisor offered their support in the process. I think for Europe it is more typical to be funded through the advisor, though. If I am not mistaken.

Comment: Actually, it would be useful to know whether an email from you would be a "cold contact" or would they recognize the sender from some previous contact. Met at a conference, previous communication... anything.

Comment: Being funded through an advisor is probably more common, but it's not necessarily the most attractive option. Depending on the funding program, a self-funded post-doc may 1. add more weight on your CV, since it shows your capability to attract funding (most important), 2. give you more attractive working conditions, 3. add an attractive label to your CV. A highly selective and renowned European post-doc program are the Marie Skłodowska-Curie postdoctoral fellowships.

Answer (score 2):

One year in advance is definitely a good point in time to reach out to potential post-doc supervisors.

- Some of them might in the near future have funding available that they could use to fund your position, or know colleagues that do. Then it's useful if you're already on their radar.
- Some might be interested in supporting your own project proposal which would lead to a self-funded position - note that it can easily take a year from the start of the proposal writing process to the decision.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to start as early as possible once you know in which direction you want to go.
Even if it means enlarging your network for now more than talking about postdocs.

I am a few months from my dissertation (with no date yet so might be a year from now with the covid situation) and I already started contacting potential post-doc advisors. So far, I have not got any negative feedbacks.

It is a good way to show your interest in their research and your interest in working with them. Some will tell you they will retire soon and they might redirect you to someone else. Some will inform you that they are starting funding applications soon.
It is a good way to see who works with who and build that network little by little.

If you want to plan strategically, I'd say you could start as soon as you know when you will have your dissertation, and a few months before the funding calls so that if they want to work with you you could already work on funding applications.

Answer (score 0):

In the fields and countries I am aware of in Europe, openings for post-doc positions will generally be advertised. There is little to be gained by cold calling potential advisors to look for one. The more likely outcome is annoying them (especially if they don't know you).

Of course, there is nothing wrong with letting you network know that you will be on the job market, and asking them if they know of any upcoming openings. Also make sure you are on any relevant mailing lists through which positions in your field may be announced (e.g. COST networks if they exist).

More productive may be to look for any open calls for fellowship applications that you may be eligible for. For example, the Marie Curie program of the EU, but also look at what the national funding agencies in the countries you want to go to may have to offer. You can approach potential advisor with the question if they want to sponsor your application. This shows initiative from your end. And even if the application(s) end up failing, it will put you on the radar of the potential advisor for any openings they may have in the future.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, there is a point to be made about hiring timelines. If OP is a strong candidate and the potential advisor wants to hire them, they might make sure that the advertisement is out as soon as possible, potentially with a rather minimal application period.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Even then, approaching them about writing a fellowship is more likely to make them think of you as a strong candidate.